# числовой параметр в ng-model превращает текстовое поле ввода в числовое

Tags: html, angularjs, валидация

Этот вопрос больше в тему "где покапаться, чтобы найти причину".

**Суть**:
Есть текстовое поле с привязкой к модели

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.numValue" z-float>
```

переменная `numValue` - обнуляемый *double* в модели.

**Непонятки:**
Поле не воспринимает десятичные без бризовского `z-float`. Введение числа, первым знаком, превращает поле в числовое, не смотря на `type="text"`, т.е. ввести букву или запятую оно не дает. Если первый знак буква, то всё ок.
В проекте есть подобные поля для ввода чисел, где всё работает, как надо.
Если дататип `ng-model` - *string*, то тогда всё опять ок.

Подозреваю, что дело в ангуляровской собственной валидации.

Заказчик требует запятую для разделения десятичных. Бьюсь уже несколько дней над этой проблемой. Может, у кого-то есть идеи, в чём причина?

**АПДЕЙТ**:
Я не буду добавлять ответ, потому что по сути это не ответ. Причина в Breeze Entity Manager. Совершенно точную причину такого поведения установить не удалось. Но суть в том, что Breeze добавляет свою валидацию при наличии ранее записанных для этой модели данных менеджером. 
Решение на данный момент сменить модель на *string* и добавить директиву на валидацию введённых символов.

Comment: что за `z-float`?

Comment: http://www.getbreezenow.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesfloat

Comment: то есть с ней все работает так как надо? а если убрать, то ошибка?

Comment: без нее вообще не воспринимает десятичные (например, 1.3), при том, что поле текстовое. Запятые не воспринимает. Если первое число, то больше не даёт ввести буквы (например "а123" нормально, а "123а" уже не проходит.

Comment: какая версия ангуляра? как-то не похоже на правду: [простой пример где все работает](http://plnkr.co/edit/AM5tLiXc5xeaFub1uM9G?p=preview) попробуй изменить его так, чтобы воспроизводилась твоя проблема

Comment: 1.5.3 версия. 
Мне вот тоже уже пару дней не верится..  
Проблема в том, что в "нормальных" условиях всё работает, но именно с этой переменной в нашем приложении нет. С другими подобными все ок. Поэтому я не могу воспроизвести проблему где-либо еще. (проблема именно приложения, на других машинах проверялось). Допускаю, что где-то что-то еще даёт такой эффект, но что это, пока установить не удалось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51515/discussion-between-grundy-and-jane-doe).